# Selecting A Single Polygon that Contains a Specific Point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

I am trying to merge the polygon features with the point that falls inside of it using a spatial join.  The problem I'm running into is that if I select 'contains' it selects both polygons. If I select 'completely contains' it doesn't select either.

I have to zoom in pretty close to see the point is in one polygon and not the other, is there a way to enhance the selection precision?
Are there any other things that I can try?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.0 SP5

[image: Example, 1:1]

Comment: How close do you have to zoom in to see what polygon a point falls within, what does the scale box say? I've noticed if you zoom in too far what you see isn't actually a true representation of the feature relative position. It may be that the point is snapped to the polygon vertices.

Instead of a spatial join ave you tried using the union geoprocessing tool? This allow for some fiddling around with snapping tolerances.

Comment: The map above is at 1:1.  It isn't snapping since the data comes from a 3rd party.  I haven't tried the Union tool, it only lets me select polygons and not the point class.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the xy tolerance of Spatial Join tool. To do so:

- Open Spatial join tool and fill the parameters as needed.
- Click Envirnments... button
- In XY Resolution and Tolerance section, input a low xy tolerance.

the tolerance must be less that the distance between the point and the edge of your right polygon

Comment: I changed it all the way down to a fraction of a mm and same result. This is a good thing to know now tho, thanks